# Hierarchy based on three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to have rows like a single table like the following

```
id name parentId
```

My current tables are (keys between them are foreign keys)

```
category
id name
```

which is the parent of all 
and

```
subcategory
id name catId
```

and the last table which is activity

```
activity
id name subcatId
```

For the parentId of category table, it would be nothing as category is the parent of all

My attempt so far have been unsuccessful

Sample Data

```
category
C-1  HR null
C-2  Development null

subcategory
SC-1 Hiring  C-1
SC-2 Admin C-1
SC-3 Developer C-2

activity
A-1 College Hiring SC-1
A-2 Job Fair SC-1
A-3 Java Development SC-3


Result Needed
1 HR null
2 Development null
3 Hiring C-1
4 Admin C-1
5 Developer C-2
6 College SC-1
7 Job Fair SC-1
8 Java Development SC-3
```

I hope it is clearer. If you need any further information, please let me know
Thanks

my attempt on 2 tables

```
select name 
from (
    select c.name   
    from category c 
    union all
    select b.name 
    from subcategory b
        inner join category ca
            on ca.id = b.parentId
     )
```

I get an error saying

> Every derived table must have its own alias

Do I need to add the following lines to my query

```
start with parent_id is null
connect by prior id = parent_id
```

Comment: sample data and expected result would help.

Comment: Add an alias after the closing bracket.. like this -- > `) A` .. Then you try execute again

Comment: those were 2 tables, how to expand it to 3 tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT @id := @id + 1 AS id, name, parent_id
FROM ( SELECT name, NULL AS parent_id FROM category
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id, name, catId FROM subcategory
       UNION ALL
       SELECT id, name, parentId FROM activity
     ) q,
     ( SELECT @id := 0 ) w;
```

- Used `UNION ALL` to concatenate the results from multiple queries.
- In `UNION` the column names of the first query is used as column names of the result set.
- Used variable `@id` and the assignment operator `:=` to generate the calculated values of the column `ID`.
- Be advised: If you use `LIMIT` or `OFFSET`, the values of column `id` would not be coherent.

Comment: Hi Usagi, may I know this query is for which MySQL version? Because my testing on MySQL 5.5, @id returned `NULL`.

Comment: Now it works! Wow, I haven't use that function before. This will be very useful in my environment!

Comment: Please also explain your work so next time I know what to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, like this should solve your problem:

```
select name 
from (
    select c.name   
    from category c 
    union all
    select b.name 
    from subcategory b
        inner join category ca
            on ca.id = b.parentId
     ) A -- alias is required for sub-query.
```

You can set anything as alias provided that it won't conflict with some of MySQL reserved word. You can set like this as well `) AS A`.

For you situation, I don't think it's necessary to do sub-query or inner join. If you really want the result to be like that you can just use union all:

```
SELECT name,'' as ID from category
UNION ALL
SELECT name,catId FROM subcategory
UNION ALL
SELECT name,subcatId FROM activity;
```

Comment: The issue is that I need the parentId as well as well as a generated Id (please see expected result). Thanks !

Comment: Yes, i noticed that @EshanI. .. Sorry, I have updated my answer, please check thank you.